# ¿como mandar el parametro Authorization desde una petición en el header en c# servicio soap?

Tags: c#, soapui

lo tengo implementado en soap ui pero la verdad no sé como llevarlo a mi codigo en c#
[image: Authorization]

ademàs el endpoint recibe usuario y clave [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Cual es el problema?? tu descripcion es muy poco clara...

Comment: Lo primero, las credenciales que estés usando en esa Authorization deberían ser cambiadas ya que las has publicado a internet. En cuanto a tu pregunta ¿cómo estás llamando a esta API, desde el HttpClient de .NET?

Comment: muchas gracias,  me indicaron que ademas debo enviar un password digest y unos atributos en el request, nonce, created y token adicional,  el llamado lo estoy haciendo como generalmente se hace para consumir un servicio soap